# Understanding CSRF when using AJAX and Web API 2

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, csrf, csrf-protection

So here is my question: How does one implement a CSRF for an AJAX call to a Web API 2 web service and have it verified? If the client side creates the CSRF token:

```
// using jQuery
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

And the AJAX sends it within the header:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "http://dev-blahblah/newWS/PostData",
    beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie("csrftoken"));
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    },
    data: {
        theID: "2135648792",
        empImg: "false"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
    }
});
```

Now that's all good and well but the real question is: **How does the server side know its a legit CSRF Token** if it never knows what it is in the first place (Since it was created client side)?

To me this seems like a waste of time if the server side never knows what has been created on the client side and really only looks if there's a token being sent in the header. Couldn't someone just inject a random token there when passing the information to the server and wouldn't the server be fine with it since it doesn't know what the token is actually supposed to be?

So with all that said, an example (in a flow view) would look like this:

```
 -Web page loads up
  |--Button is clicked to fire off AJAX req.
     |--On the fly a token is created for the header.
        |--Header is sent to the server as a check to see if one is there.
           |--Regardless what the token value is, if the server sees it then its fine and continues.
```

So again, maybe I am looking at this the incorrect way, but I just don't see this as a secure way of seeing if someone is tying to hack the web service.

Comment: How is the client creating the CSRF token exactly? I see that `getCookie` is reading a cookie value, but presumably the server created and sent the cookie value; the client is just reading it and sending it back as a header. The server will ensure that the `X-CSRFToken` header value it receives is the same as the cookie it sent in a previous response.

Comment: @kuporific Thanks for the reply. How does one get a token if the page in question is a normal HTML page and not a asp.net page then?